# IBM BLUEMIX BLOCKCHAIN SDK-DEMO failing

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I have been working with HFC SDK for Node.js and it used to work, but since last night I am having some problems.

When running helloblockchain.js only few times works, most time I get this error when it tries to enroll a new user:

```
E0113 11:56:05.983919636    5288 handshake.c:128]            Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1484304965.983872199","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1484304965.983866102","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":948}]}

Error:  Failed to register and enroll JohnDoe: Error
```

Other times, the enroll works and the failure appears deploying the chaincode:

```
Enrolled and registered JohnDoe successfully

Deploying chaincode ...
E0113 12:14:27.341527043    5455 handshake.c:128]            Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1484306067.341430168","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1484306067.341421859","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":948}]}

Failed to deploy chaincode: request={"fcn":"init","args":["a","100","b","200"],"chaincodePath":"chaincode","certificatePath":"/certs/peer/cert.pem"}, error={"error":{"code":14,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}}},"msg":"Error"}
```

Or:

```
Enrolled and registered JohnDoe successfully

Deploying chaincode ...
E0113 12:15:27.448867739    5483 handshake.c:128]            Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1484306127.448692244","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1484306127.448668047","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":948}]}
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error
at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/hfc/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/hfc/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:158:8)
at readCallback (/usr/lib/node_modules/hfc/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:217:12)
E0113 12:15:27.563487641    5483 handshake.c:128]            Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1484306127.563437122","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1484306127.563429661","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":948}]}
```

This code worked yesterday, so I don't know what could be happening.

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

Thanks,
Javier.

## ibm-bluemix

## blockchain

Answer (score 0):

These types of intermittent issues are usually related to GRPC.  An initial suggestion is to ensure that you are using at least GRPC version 1.0.0.

If you are using a Mac, then the maximum number of open file descriptors should be checked (using `ulimit -n`).  Sometimes this is initially set to a low value such as 256, so increasing the value could help.

There are a couple of GRPC issues with similar symptoms.

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8732
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8839
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8382

There is a `grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms` property that is mentioned in some of these issues.  Increasing the value past the 1000 ms level might help reduce the frequency of issues.  Below are instructions for how the helloblockchain.js file can be modified to set this property to a higher value.

1. Open the helloblockchain.js file in the Hyperledger Fabric Client example and find the `enrollAndRegisterUsers` function.
2. Add  `“grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms": 5000` to the `setMemberServicesUrl` call.

   ```
   chain.setMemberServicesUrl(ca_url, {
           pem: cert, "grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms": 5000
   });
   ```
3. Add  `“grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms": 5000` to the `addPeer` call.

   ```
   chain.addPeer("grpcs://" + peers[i].discovery_host + ":" + peers[i].discovery_port, 
   {pem: cert, "grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms": 5000
   });
   ```

Note that setting the `grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms` property may reduce the frequency of issues, but it will not necessarily eliminate all issues.

The connection to the eventhub that is made in the helloblockchain.js file can also be a factor.  There is an earlier version of the Hyperledger Fabric Client that does not utilize the eventhub.  This earlier version could be tried to determine if this makes a difference.  After running `git clone https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/SDK-Demo.git`, run `git checkout b7d5195` to use this prior level.  Before running `node helloblockchain.js` from a Node.js command window, the `git status` command can be used to check the code level that is being used.