# Bluemix blockchain throwing intermittent errors while sending invoke transactions

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to populate bluemix blockchain with data by sending invoke transactions.
After a few records get processed, suddenly the below exception occurs:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: {"created":"@1491562391.771888837","description":"RST_STREAM","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_rst_stream.c","file_line":107,"http2_error":2}
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/hyperledger/bluemix-deploy/sc-visibility-poc/rest-services/populator-service/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
    at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/home/hyperledger/bluemix-deploy/sc-visibility-poc/rest-services/populator-service/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:169:8)
    at /home/hyperledger/bluemix-deploy/sc-visibility-poc/rest-services/populator-service/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:634:14
```

NOTE: I am using HFC version 0.6.5 and bluemkix blockchain is using fabric version 0.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a GRPC issue.  Version 0.6.5 of the Hyperledger Fabric Client is the right version to use with an instance of the Blockchain service on Bluemix which utilizes Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1.  The GRPC version that is being used in conjunction with the Hyperleger Fabric Client should be checked.  The version of GRPC should be at least 1.0.0.

If you are running the Hyperleger Fabric Client on a Mac, then the maximum number of open file descriptors should be checked since sometimes the default value is small.

There is a [prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633491/ibm-bluemix-blockchain-sdk-demo-failing/41859772#41859772ttp://) that mentions similar symptoms, so the suggestions in that response might be helpful.

Comment: Tried the above given suggestions, but it is not resolving the error :(.     The GRPC version is 1.0.0 and also adding the “grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms": 5000 to addmembersrvc and addpeer does not help. I am using linux environment and number of open file descriptors is 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reenroll the user using the same enrollment certificate in your hyperledger fabric client directory? This does not work in 0.6.
Try enrolling a new user or use a different instance of blockchain service on bluemix.