# Can't deploy .bna network definition to Bluemix, multiple errors

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to deploy car auction sample .bna file to HLF v0.6 service on Bluemix and getting different errors.

1. My connection profile for Bluemix:

   ```
   {
   "type": "hlf",
   "membershipServicesURL": "grpcs://1c0b2dabbb834804ae3d284fed9059f4-ca.us.blockchain.ibm.com:30002",
   "peerURL": "grpcs://1c0b2dabbb834804ae3d284fed9059f4-vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com:30002",
   "eventHubURL": "grpcs://1c0b2dabbb834804ae3d284fed9059f4-vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com:31002",
   "keyValStore": "/Users/me/.composer-credentials",
   "deployWaitTime": "3000",
   "invokeWaitTime": "1000",
   "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nEa8/B6hPatJ0ES8q/HO3X8IVQwVs1n3aAr0im0/T+Xc=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDrzCCApegAwIBAgIQCDvgVpBCRrGhdWrJWZHHSjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBh\nMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3\nd3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSAwHgYDVQQDExdEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgUm9vdCBD\nQTAeFw0wNjExMTAwMDAwMDBaFw0zMTExMTAwMDAwMDBaMGExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\nMRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxGTAXBgNVBAsTEHd3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5j\nb20xIDAeBgNVBAMTF0RpZ2lDZXJ0IEdsb2JhbCBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG\n9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4jvhEXLeqKTTo1eqUKKPC3eQyaKl7hLOllsB\nCSDMAZOnTjC3U/dDxGkAV53ijSLdhwZAAIEJzs4bg7/fzTtxRuLWZscFs3YnFo97\nnh6Vfe63SKMI2tavegw5BmV/Sl0fvBf4q77uKNd0f3p4mVmFaG5cIzJLv07A6Fpt\n43C/dxC//AH2hdmoRBBYMql1GNXRor5H4idq9Joz+EkIYIvUX7Q6hL+hqkpMfT7P\nT19sdl6gSzeRntwi5m3OFBqOasv+zbMUZBfHWymeMr/y7vrTC0LUq7dBMtoM1O/4\ngdW7jVg/tRvoSSiicNoxBN33shbyTApOB6jtSj1etX+jkMOvJwIDAQABo2MwYTAO\nBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUA95QNVbR\nTLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUA95QNVbRTLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUw\nDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAMucN6pIExIK+t1EnE9SsPTfrgT1eXkIoyQY/Esr\nhMAtudXH/vTBH1jLuG2cenTnmCmrEbXjcKChzUyImZOMkXDiqw8cvpOp/2PV5Adg\n06O/nVsJ8dWO41P0jmP6P6fbtGbfYmbW0W5BjfIttep3Sp+dWOIrWcBAI+0tKIJF\nPnlUkiaY4IBIqDfv8NZ5YBberOgOzW6sRBc4L0na4UU+Krk2U886UAb3LujEV0ls\nYSEY1QSteDwsOoBrp+uvFRTp2InBuThs4pFsiv9kuXclVzDAGySj4dzp30d8tbQk\nCAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
   "certificatePath": "/certs/peer/cert.pem"
   }
   ```
2. I'm executing the following command:

`composer network deploy -p bluemix -a sample-networks/packages/carauction-network/carauction-network@0.0.7.bna -i admin -s PASSS`

I tried this many times and I'm getting one of the following errors:

I. Security handshake:

```
    $ composer network deploy -p bluemix -a sample-networks/packages/carauction-network/carauction-network@0.0.7.bna -i admin -s 97b116b3c4

    Deploying business network from archive:  carauction-network/carauction-network@0.0.7.bna
    Business network definition:
        Identifier: carauction-network@0.0.7
        Description: Car Auction Business Network

    E0528 10:59:18.962200000 123145570217984 handshake.c:128]
    Security handshake failed:
    {"created":"@1495940358.962177000","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1495940358.962172000","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_poll_posix.c","file_line":427}]}

    Error
    Command failed
```

II. Unhandled 'error' event:

```
    $ composer network deploy -p bluemix -a sample-networks/packages/carauction-network/carauction-network@0.0.7.bna -i admin -s 97b116b3c4

    Deploying business network from archive:  carauction-network/carauction-network@0.0.7.bna
    Business network definition:
        Identifier: carauction-network@0.0.7
        Description: Car Auction Business Network

    events.js:160
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

    Error: unknown service protos.Events
        at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
        at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:169:8)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:634:14
```

III. Identity or token does not match:

```
    $ composer network deploy -p bluemix -a sample-networks/packages/carauction-network/carauction-network@0.0.7.bna -i admin -s 97b116b3c4

    Deploying business network from archive:  carauction-network/carauction-network@0.0.7.bna
    Business network definition:
        Identifier: carauction-network@0.0.7
        Description: Car Auction Business Network


    Error: Identity or token does not match.
    Command failed
```

I feel "SSL Handshake problem" (I) and "Unhandled 'error' event" (II) are related to the old issue with [HFC not handling properly GRPC disconnects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633491/ibm-bluemix-blockchain-sdk-demo-failing) Is it correct?. What I can't figure out is what's causing "Identity or token does not match" (III). My current guess is that `admin` user does not have a wallet created yet (can't see it in my `~/.composer-credentials` folder). Is `composer deploy` supposed to create wallet automatically if it does not yet exists?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some more experiments, and here is what I've learned:

1. It was a problem in my profile's connection.json. When I copied and modified one from the answer to this question: [Fabric composer integration with Bluemix blockchain service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309207/fabric-composer-integration-with-bluemix-blockchain-service) it start working.
2. I was setting long timeouts in `connection.json`, but CLI command still ends with the following error:

   ```
   events.js:160
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
   ^

   Error: {"created":"@1496109180.720017000","description":"Secure read failed","file":"../src/core/lib/security/transport/secure_endpoint.c","file_line":157,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1496109180.720007000","description":"OS Error","errno":54,"file":"../src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.c","file_line":229,"os_error":"Connection reset by peer","syscall":"recvmsg"}]}
       at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
       at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:169:8)
       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:634:14
   ```

At the same time chaicode gets deployed. Still not sure what is causing it.

3. Since composer's deployment command is finished with error, the mapping between composer's network ID and deployed chaincode ID isn't added to. Which means, it needs to be added manually, by adding something like this to a respective `connection.json`:

   ```
   "networks": {
           "carauction-network": "8f637b9886357fb3e24864cfa36f9cdae84e587028a08074d856e9b6635afa76"
       }
   ```